# How to create horizontal and vertical scroll bars

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How to create horizontal and vertical scrollbars like [this](http://trello.com) page without using any plugin. Here is what I want: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg3hx.jpg)

[image: 02]

Answer (score 2):

To do this you will first need to set a fixed height (for vertical scrolling) or fixed width (for horizontal scrolling) on the container.  Then you can use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to tell the browser how to handle content that extends outside of that width/height. In this case you want to use the `scroll` option, or `auto`. `scroll` means the scrollbars will *always* be shown, `auto` means the browser will only show the scrollbars if there is enough content to require it.

```
.scroll-horizontal {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 200px;
}

.scroll-vertical {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks gnack so much,
I use auto. height and max-height :100%. but to do two scrolling operations, is not well

Comment: If you combine those four rules on a single element you should get a scrollbar each way.

Comment: I want to do the same trello page, ^^

Answer (score 1):

write this code in the beginning of the HTML.

```
<style>
div.scroll {
            margin: 4px, 4px;
            padding: 4px;
            background-color: white;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

</style>
```

Now, to enter the scrollable content,

```
<div class="scroll">  PUT YOUR SCROLLABLE CONTENT HERE </div>
```

**Note** that the scroll bar only appear if the content is long enough to be scrolled.
This is because we have overflow-x: auto; in our code.
You can adjust the size of the content by adjusting the height and width value from 200 px.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
elementname {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

if you want to format a scroll bar then use plugins named 'jScrollPane'
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: spam is not usually seen in stack exchange.Why is this not getting enough downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have more content and less space. Using `max-width` would help. You could do this:

```css
     .container {
         max-height: 400px;
         max-width: 150px;
         overflow: scroll;
     }

     .container img {
         height: 150px;
         width: 200px;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT1ZWmDmLtw3Sfe0m3Wr5lebVoWscbNYLqNDw&usqp=CAU">
        <img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/68786770d80b99847a142d61e5e856db/c82638bdf14ad922-7d/s540x810/b9567b3f3688b0aedcaa27e01d88581748246a3c.gifv">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHBgNrR68UVJSl-Nwz-du8j21Wzg_r1cYReQ&usqp=CAU">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT0TtddmwGTMQ9XWnDu28gxUaNNDf81Q3fuYQ&usqp=CAU">
    </div>
```